Series expansion of a given function
I attempt to do the series expansion for the following function
Simplify[Series[((-5)^(1/
        6) (2 + (-2 + ξ3) ξ3 + (-2 + ξ4) ξ4) a[
      1])/((-1 + ξ3)^2 ξ3^4 (-6 + 5 ξ3)^(4/
        5) (-1 + ξ4)^2 ξ4 (-6 + 5 ξ4)^(1/5)), {ξ3, 0, 
   1}], Im[ξ3] == 0]

Note that this function is expected to expand this function to order $\xi_3$. However, it fails to capture order $\frac{1}{\xi_3}$ term

If I slightly modify the code to expand the function to order $\xi^2$, then I could get the correct order $\frac{1}{\xi_3}$ term


I'm getting the same result for each. One is perhaps less simplified than the other, but they are equivalent.

@DanielLichtblau I attached my mma result. Maybe it's because my version is a bit old? It's 12

It is possible this improved in the last few releases. I know some issues with getting correct order for Series were addressed in this time frame.

@DanielLichtblau Thanks for this info. Perhaps the best way is to update my Mathematica...

I am not sure why this is happening, but here's a quick fix. Do a replacement $\xi_3 \rightarrow \tfrac{1}{x_3}$ and then expand around $\infty$.
expr = ((-5)^(1/
        6) (2 + (-2 + ξ3) ξ3 + (-2 + ξ4) ξ4) a[
      1])/((-1 + ξ3)^2 ξ3^4 (-6 + 5 ξ3)^(4/
        5) (-1 + ξ4)^2 ξ4 (-6 + 5 ξ4)^(1/5));
expr /. ξ3 :> 1/xx3;
Series[%, {xx3, Infinity, 1}]
Coefficient[%, xx3]





Use Assuming.
Assuming[\[Xi]3 \[Element] Reals, 
 Series[((-5)^(1/
         6)  (2 + (-2 + \[Xi]3)  \[Xi]3 + (-2 + \[Xi]4)  \[Xi]4)  a[
       1])/((-1 + \[Xi]3)^2  \[Xi]3^4  (-6 + 5  \[Xi]3)^(4/
         5)  (-1 + \[Xi]4)^2  \[Xi]4  (-6 + 5  \[Xi]4)^(1/
         5)), {\[Xi]3, 0, 1}] // Simplify]





Do you know why does Assuming help here?

@Vayne In your code, you told Simplify that Im[ξ3] == 0, but you didn't tell Series that. Assuming let both of them know that.

Thanks! But why does the additional assumption could help series expansion capture 1/\xi term?
